# How to include custom template-url ui.bootstrap.datepicker and add json data to the date fields

Tags: json, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Am trying to create a fare calendar, which can display the fares on a particular day under each date in calendar using UI bootstrap datepicker.The calendar display is absolutely fine.

When I was researching, I realised I need to use a template-url and override the current template, such that I can insert the json values under the dates

Here is my code so far

HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.js"></script>
    <script src="democtrl.js"></script>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<style>
  .full button span {
    background-color: limegreen;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
  .partially button span {
    background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 32px;
    color: black;
  }
  .birthday {
                    background: transparent url('cake.png') no-repeat 0 50%;
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 16px;
                    height: 16px;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    margin-right: 3px;
                }
</style>
<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
    <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>

    <h4>Inline</h4>
    <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
      <datepicker ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm" custom-class="getDayClass(date, mode)"></datepicker>
    </div>

    <h4>Popup</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2020-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="date" class="form-control" datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2020-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Format:</label> <select class="form-control" ng-model="format" ng-options="f for f in formats"><option></option></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="today()">Today</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="dt = '2009-08-24'">2009-08-24</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="toggleMin()" tooltip="After today restriction">Min date</button>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS file:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.clear = function () {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
  };

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
  };
  $scope.toggleMin();

  $scope.open = function($event) {
    $scope.status.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
  };

  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];

  $scope.status = {
    opened: false
  };



      var tomorrow = new Date();
          tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);

      var nextDay = new Date();
      nextDay.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2);

      var afterTomorrow = new Date();
      afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 3);

  $scope.events =
    [
      {
        date: tomorrow,
        status: 'full'
      },
      {
        date: nextDay,
        status: 'full'
      },
      {
        date: afterTomorrow,
        status: 'birthday'
      }
    ];


  $scope.getDayClass = function(date, mode) {
    if (mode === 'day') {
      var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

      for (var i=0;i<$scope.events.length;i++){
        var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

        if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {

          return $scope.events[i].status;
        }
      }
    }

    return '';
  };
});
```

I see the current template for day in tpls file:

```
angular.module("template/datepicker/day.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/datepicker/day.html",
    "<table role=\"grid\" aria-labelledby=\"{{::uniqueId}}-title\" aria-activedescendant=\"{{activeDateId}}\">\n" +
    "  <thead>\n" +
    "    <tr>\n" +
    "      <th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left\" ng-click=\"move(-1)\" tabindex=\"-1\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\"></i></button></th>\n" +
    "      <th colspan=\"{{::5 + showWeeks}}\"><button id=\"{{::uniqueId}}-title\" role=\"heading\" aria-live=\"assertive\" aria-atomic=\"true\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm\" ng-click=\"toggleMode()\" ng-disabled=\"datepickerMode === maxMode\" tabindex=\"-1\" style=\"width:100%;\"><strong>{{title}}</strong></button></th>\n" +
    "      <th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right\" ng-click=\"move(1)\" tabindex=\"-1\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></i></button></th>\n" +
    "    </tr>\n" +
    "    <tr>\n" +
    "      <th ng-if=\"showWeeks\" class=\"text-center\"></th>\n" +
    "      <th ng-repeat=\"label in ::labels track by $index\" class=\"text-center\"><small aria-label=\"{{::label.full}}\">{{::label.abbr}}</small></th>\n" +
    "    </tr>\n" +
    "  </thead>\n" +
    "  <tbody>\n" +
    "    <tr ng-repeat=\"row in rows track by $index\">\n" +
    "      <td ng-if=\"showWeeks\" class=\"text-center h6\"><em>{{ weekNumbers[$index] }}</em></td>\n" +
    "      <td ng-repeat=\"dt in row track by dt.date\" class=\"text-center\" role=\"gridcell\" id=\"{{::dt.uid}}\" ng-class=\"::dt.customClass\">\n" +
    "        <button type=\"button\" style=\"min-width:100%;\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm\" ng-class=\"{'btn-info': dt.selected, active: isActive(dt)}\" ng-click=\"select(dt.date)\" ng-disabled=\"dt.disabled\" tabindex=\"-1\"><span ng-class=\"::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}\">{{::dt.label}}</span></button>\n" +
    "      </td>\n" +
    "    </tr>\n" +
    "  </tbody>\n" +
    "</table>\n" +
    "");
}]);
```

I just need to insert the json data below the date.But I am quite not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Way *way* too much code. Simplify and reduce your code to an illustrative example to have any hope of someone helping.

Comment: Solved it myself.Thankyou.:)Sure will reduce number of lines next time:)

Comment: Add snippet next time

Comment: If you solved something, is this a good idea to answer your question? -1

Comment: Yes, tell us how you solved it.

Comment: can you post your answer?